# jQuery Validation Engine with jQuery 1.4.2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Has anyone used the jQuery Validation Engine (at http://posabsolute.github.com/jQuery-Validation-Engine/) with jQuery 1.4.2? In the documentation, they use jQuery 1.4.4; but I can't find any information on the oldest version that this plugin was tested with. We're trying to get it to work with jQuery 1.4.2. Has anyone tried using this plugin with older versions of jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that as of August 2012, the most recent version of this particular plugin actually requires jQuery 1.7.2 or above to work. The documentation seems a bit outdated in that respect.

The demo of this script came with a minimized copy of jQuery 1.7.2, and it worked.

I tried downloading a copy of jQuery 1.4.4 and calling that in the page, to see if that would work, like the documentation seemed to indicate. jQuery Validation Engine did not work. (It also works with jQuery 1.8.0, which has a smaller footprint than 1.7.2.)